# How to provide stereotype for Package in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I am trying to create EA package from C# Addin. I am able to create the package but, when I am trying to set the stereotype for package from C# code then its not getting set. 
I am using the below code to set the stereotype for package.

```
packageCreate = (EA.Package)getModel.Packages.AddNew(pacName, "");
                    packageCreate.StereotypeEx = "TCL";
                    packageCreate.Update();
```

How to provide Stereotype to EA Package using C# ?

Comment: Is `Update()` returning `true`?

Comment: Yes update() is returning true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the stereotype to the package's element

```
packageCreate.Update();
packageCreate.Element.StereotypeEx = "TCL";
packageCreate.Update();
```

The difference between `Stereotype` and `StereotypeEx` is subtile. `Stereotype` delivers the first stereo of a list while `Ex` returns a comma separated list. When assigning stereos, the `Ex` variant splits by comma first and assigns each separately. `Stereotype`in contrast stores the value directly and this results in really strange effects.

This and other `Ex` properties were introduced in later EA versions. So rather than fixing the basic one, they added an extra property to increase confusion. EAUI.

Comment: I'd consider this a bug, but the Sparxians have a quite sloppy interpretation of what us Earthlings regard as such. So let's call that once again EA Unique Interface :-/

Comment: @Thomas...Can you please explain the difference between Stereotype and StereotypeEx ?